# pandas.read_csv returns empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

here is my csv file:

```
uipid,shid,pass,camera,pointheight,pointxpos,PointZPos,deffound,HighestHeight,XPosition,ZPosition,RLevel,Rejected,MixedP
50096853911,6345214,1,SXuXeXCamera,218,12600,82570,no,-1,-1,-1,880,no,498
49876879038,6391743,1,SZuZeZCamera,313,210400,187807,no,-1,-1,-1,880,no,388
```

Here is my code:

```
df=pd.read_csv('.\sources\data.csv', delimiter=',', names=['uipid','shid','pass','camera','pointheight','pointxpos','PointZPos','deffound','HighestHeight', 'XPosition','ZPosition','RLevel','Rejected','MixedP'], skip_blank_lines=True, skipinitialspace=True, engine='python')
```

and when I select a column `print(df.loc[(df['uipid']==50096853911))`I get an empty df.

> Empty DataFrame 
>   Columns[uipid,shid,pass,camera,pointheight,pointxpos,PointZPos,deffound,HighestHeight,XPosition,ZPosition,RLevel,Rejected,MixedP]
>   Index: []

And when i set the `dtype` in `pd.read_csv`:

```
df=pd.read_csv('.\sources\data.csv', delimiter=',' ,dtype={'uipid':int, 'shid': int, 'pass':int, 'camera':str, 'pointheight':int, 'pointxpos':int , 'PointZPos':int, 'deffound':str, 'HighestHeight':int, 'XPosition':int,'ZPosition':int, 'RLevel':int, 'Rejected':str, 'MixedP':int}, names=['uipid','shid','pass','camera','pointheight','pointxpos','PointZPos','deffound','HighestHeight', 'XPosition','ZPosition','RLevel','Rejected','MixedP'], skip_blank_lines=True, index_col=False, encoding="utf-8", skipinitialspace=True)
```

I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('int32')
>   according to the rule 'safe'
>
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'uipid'

Comment: Did you check if that value exists at all for that column? as your original code seems correct to me. Also you shouldn't need to specify those args, the following should work fine: `df=pd.read_csv('.\sources\data.csv', skip_blank_lines=True, skipinitialspace=True)`

Comment: yes the value exists..

Comment: It looks like you have syntax error try this: `print(df.loc[df['uipid']==50096853911])` you're passing a tuple previously. Actually that would still work, please post raw data, your code to create the df, your code that produces the error as what you've posted doesn't demonstrate this

Comment: Try `header = 0` in your `read_csv` with `names=`

Comment: @pshep123 is correct, by passing `names` here you're treating the existing column row as a data row, so it becomes the first row, this then converts the dtypes to be object or in fact `str` for all the rows, you can prove this by trying `print(df.loc[df['uipid']=='50096853911'])` and also it seems unnecessary to pass the column names if they match the existing column rows

Comment: Show us the output of `df.info()`

Comment: You specify uipid as `int` when you read the csv, then try to compare it to a string (when you put quotes around the number). Pick one or the other and you won't have the type issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting `header = 0` in your second `read_csv` example and let us know if it works.

Comment: OK, if i have header=0 then I dont get the error : Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('int32') according to the rule 'safe'

Comment: Can you be a little more descriptive with your new problem?

Comment: When I used:

df=pd.read_csv('.\sources\data.csv', delimiter=',', header=0) and 
print(df.loc[(df[uipid]==50096853911)]) 


I got the result. Thanks for your solution and sorry if I was confusing!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df_trail=pd.read_csv('/content/New Text Document.txt',
  delimiter=',',
  names=['uipid', 'shid', 'pass', 'camera', 'pointheight', 'pointxpos', 'PointZPos', 'deffound', 'HighestHeight', 'XPosition', 'ZPosition', 'RLevel', 'Rejected', 'MixedP'],
  skip_blank_lines=True, skipinitialspace=True, engine='python',header=0)
```